# Can I link a PC to two separate networks and transfer files between them?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-xp, router

I have a PC running Windows XP, that is connected to a specific network with a CNC machine. The CNC is connected to the router.

My main PC is running Windows 10 and is also connected to the same router. I would like to transfer files from my main PC to the XP PC. I can see the XP on the network, but it's not connected and was wondering if I have to set up a new connection through the XP PC to join the network that runs the main PC?

I currently transfer files via USB, but this is not optimal.

Comment: *"I can see the XP machine on the network"* - To clarify, you can see the XP machine on the network with the Windows 10 machine? Also, have you checked the XP machine to see if it can see your Windows 10 machine?

Comment: I don't understand how you can say you see it on the network but it's "not connected". In what way is it not connected if you can see it on the network?

Comment: @Anaksunaman - yes, I can see the XP machine on the Windows 10 machine, but not the other way around

Comment: @Spiff - when I open network, it shows a list of devices like TV, printer and so on. The XP machine has a wifi symbol and says not connected

Answer (score 1):

1. You could install ssh server and client.  Then use scp or possible winscp to do a secure connection.
2. Save your files to a cloud like google drive on computer A and retrieve them on computer B.
3. Manually turn SMB1 support ON transfer the file and turn it OFF again.
4. SFTP old but possible.
5. Install apache or etc use the firewall to limit access to the XP computer on port 80/443.  Goto firefox/chrome/etc on XP computer download the files.
6. Bit torrent server and client, this is overkill but still possible.
7. Other software with the server/client setup exist you could use.
8. Email the files to yourself. check email on XP computer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can connect this way. I have the setup here and connecting from Windows 10 to XP Pro give the SMB error " cannot connect to the share because it requires SMBv1 which is obsolete"  So in order to maintain security you need to use the USB transfer.

Comment: Actually you can enable SMBv1 on Windows 10. If there is nothing else connected to this network the security risk is practically zero. But NEVER connect that Windows 10 PC to a network you don't trust when SMBv1 is enabled. It is an open invitation to malware.

Comment: I do not recommend using SMBv1 on Windows 10 because you would have to severely limit its use to prevent issues.

Comment: Obviously. And I don't advocate it either, but if you are in a trusted network environment the risk can be manageable. I would still recommend to let the W10 box make the drive-map to XP (not the other way around) and on the W10 box to disable File/Print Sharing completely. And a dedicated user-account with different password just for that drivemap. Not to be used anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I will pass on taking the risk. It is a work network, but unsure how secure it would be.

Comment: So then is the answer above acceptable to you?